# Allow unauthenticated users to access views that utilize current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have lots of views that have elements that check if the current user isn't the same user that's being viewed, etc. For example, on the user show page there is a button that allows a user to follow another user, which doesn't appear if the user is looking at their own profile.

```
<% if current_user != @user %>
  <div id="follow_form">
    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
      <%= render 'users/unfollow' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'users/follow' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The problem arises that if you're not logged in, rails throws an error.

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

  <% if current_user.id == @user.id %>
    <%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path(@user) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'message', new_message_path(receiver_id: @user.id) %>
  ...
```

I don't want to have to force people to log in or sign up to view index or show pages. How can I get around this?

Comment: use user_signed_in? to check if any user is logged in.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it must be time for me to go to bed. :) Put it as an answer and I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try that:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
 <% if current_user != @user %>
  <div id="follow_form">
    <% if current_user.following?(@user) %>
      <%= render 'users/unfollow' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= render 'users/follow' %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```